# Cannot resolve Mockito dependency in a Tycho project

Tags: maven-3, tycho

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reference mockito within tycho?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299993/how-to-reference-mockito-within-tycho)

I am trying to get a test feature project building with Tycho, but it fails to resolve dependencies listed in my pom from the Maven central repository that is listed in my parent pom. Here is the relevant part from my parent pom:

```
    <properties>
            <tycho-version>0.12.0</tycho-version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>helios</id>
                    <layout>p2</layout>
                    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/</url>
            </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <layout>default</layout>
                    <snapshots>
                            <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                    </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                            <extensions>true</extensions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                            <version>${tycho-version}</version>

                            <configuration>
                                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies>

                                    <resolver>p2</resolver>

                                    <environments>
                                            <environment>
                                                    <os>linux</os>
                                                    <ws>gtk</ws>
                                                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                                            </environment>
                                            <environment>
                                                    <os>win32</os>
                                                    <ws>win32</ws>
                                                    <arch>x86</arch>
                                            </environment>
                                    </environments>
                            </configuration>
                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

and here my feature pom:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.example.testing.feature</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-feature</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                            <version>1.8.5</version>
                    </dependency>
            </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

when I run mvn clean package on my feature project, I get the following:

[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
[INFO] Adding repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
[DEBUG] Added p2 repository helios (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
) 
[DEBUG] Ignoring Maven repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

and then my build fails, because my dependency cannot be resolved. Am I missing something? Is this because of the p2 resolver configured for target-platform-configuration?

Comment: The most important part of the console output is missing: Which dependency cannot be resolved? Probably something in the transitive dependency chain of `org.mockito.mockito-all` (see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951980/1523648))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed it seems you are correct.

First, create a Target Definition file (.target) and put it inside a Maven project, see here for example target: https://github.com/eclipsesource/com.eclipsesource.tycho.aspectj.demo/blob/master/platform/indigo.target

You need to attach the .target file to the artifact, using the build helper:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact>
                        <file>indigo.target</file>
                        <type>target</type>
                        <classifier>indigo</classifier>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

(from https://github.com/eclipsesource/com.eclipsesource.tycho.aspectj.demo/blob/master/platform/pom.xml )

Then, in the parent POM or the plug-in projects that use that target definition file, you need to configure the "target" of target-platform-configuration Maven plugin, for example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <resolver>p2</resolver>
        <ignoreTychoRepositories>true</ignoreTychoRepositories>
        <target>
            <artifact>
                <groupId>com.eclipsesource.sandbox.weaving.demo</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.eclipsesource.sandbox.weaving.demo.platform</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <classifier>indigo</classifier>
            </artifact>
        </target>
        <environments>
            <environment>
                <os>${build.os}</os>
                <ws>${build.ws}</ws>
                <arch>${build.arch}</arch>
            </environment>
        </environments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

(taken from https://github.com/eclipsesource/com.eclipsesource.tycho.aspectj.demo/blob/master/releng/pom.xml )

Then your project(s) should build very nicely using Tycho. :-) If your .target references remote p2 repositories and not already in the p2 bundle pool, the necessary artifacts will be downloaded automatically.

Good luck!

*Known Issue:*

```
[WARNING] Target location type: Profile is not supported
```

As of Tycho 0.12.0, It means the "Eclipse Installation" target source type [cannot be used](http://software.2206966.n2.nabble.com/target-file-artifacts-tp4879861p4880268.html) with Tycho (yet?), along with "Directory" and "Features".

Solution: Use the "Update Site" target source.

If you don't have yet an update site, here's to generate an update site from an Eclipse (or from any folder containing bundles, for that matter):

```
/opt/eclipse_rcp/eclipse -consolelog -nosplash -verbose \
  -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher \
  -metadataRepository file:/home/ceefour/p2/bonita/ \
  -artifactRepository file:/home/ceefour/p2/bonita/ \
  -source /home/ceefour/BOS-5.5.1/studio/ \
  -publishArtifacts
```

Note:

- change /opt/eclipse_rcp to your own Eclipse SDK installation
- metadataRepository and artifactRepository is the folder where the new update site will be created
- source is --you guessed it-- the folder/installation containing the original bundles

Comment: This got me on the right path. I used some of the suggestions in Hendy's answer to solve my problem. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I got excatly the same problem but I can't solve it using your answer. I followed your instructions, created the target platform, created a custom p2 repo containing mockito but eclipse still can't resolve mockito. I tried to specify the dependency in the pom.xml which doesn't work (no error marker within the xml file but within eclipse). When I try to add mockito as required bundle in the manifest it doesn't show up in the list. Have you any guess what I could have been made wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This solution is too complicated. If you don't have a target file already, it is a lot faster to directly add the p2 repository containing the missing requirements the POM (with [layout=p2](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Layout_p2)).