# can we use dependencies from Eclipse p2 repository in a regular Maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, osgi-bundle, p2

I have a maven project with packaging type as jar . I have loads of normal dependencies which are present in m2 repository and some eclipse bundle dependencies which are present in p2 repo.
I can not use tycho compiler plugin as it will prohibit me from using m2 repo dependencies.
I tried adding p2 repository in pom.xml and add dependency in dependency tag -

```
<repositories>
   <repository>
       <id>test</id>
       <layout>p2</layout>
       <url>file:///C:/repo/test</url>
   </repository>
</repositories>
```

But its giving me error -

```
Failed to execute goal on project test-common: Could not resolve dependencies for project 
com.test.ce:test-common:jar:0.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at
com.test.pd:com.pd.test.xml:jar:1.2.200.003: Failed to read artifact descriptor for 
com.test.pd:com.pd.test.xml:jar:1.2.200.003: Could not transfer artifact 
com.test.pd:com.pd.test.xml:jar:1.2.200.003 from/to test (file:///C:/repo/test): 
Cannot access file:///C:/repo/test with type p2 using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: 
Cannot access file:///C:/repo/test with type p2 using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: 
Unsupported repository layout p2 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Would [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240401/how-can-i-use-eclipse-p2-repositories-from-maven) be helpful?

Comment: Not a duplicate if you take a closer look. While this question is how to use dependencies from a p2 repository for a regular maven build, the other question asks how to use regular maven dependency  in a p2 build (vice versa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the Eclipse dependencies from Maven Central (maven.org) or some other Maven repositories (like mvnrepository.com) for straight Maven builds.

For example, you can find org.eclipse.core [here](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.core%22).

Occasionally, some versions are not available on Maven Central, so you might have to try and find another compatible version.

[This article](https://objectteams.wordpress.com/2017/01/09/eclipse-neon-2-is-on-maven-central/) provides some background information.